# Memoizing a yup validation schema with useMemo

Tags: reactjs, yup

To make the i18n work with the yup validation schema, I had to make anonymous functions from the schemas and return a schema like this:

```
const Schema = () {
   return yup.object()
     .shape({
         nestedFields: NestedSchema().optional(),
     })
}

const NestedSchema = () {
   return ...
}
```

Because the schema doesn't change and got called on each render, I wanted to wrap it in useMemo like this.

```
const Schema = () {
   return useMemo(() => yup.object()
     .shape({
         nestedFields: NestedSchema().optional(),
     }), [])
}

const NestedSchema = () {
   return ...
}
```

But this gives me a black screen and bunch of console errors, with this one in particular: `Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function`

My question is: How should you memoize the entire schema (including the nested ones)?

Follow-up question: When I put the useMemo on the nested schema, it works fine. I can't make sense of that. Why does react allow me to memoize the nested schema but not the parent one?

Additional context: The yup schema is validated with useFormHook like this:

```
const { handleSubmit} = useForm({
   resolver: yupResolver(formSchema),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your component before returning anything you should do something like:

```
  const validationSchema = useMemo(
    () =>
      Yup.object().shape({
        nestedFields: NestedSchema().optional(),
      }),
    []
  )
```

As the error message state, your component shouldn't run hooks conditionally. Each and every hook of a component should always run. So you need to make sure you place the execution of your hooks before your first return.

### But, should you actually memoize this?

Lots of people think memoizing will always increase performance, so they use `useMemo` and `useCallback` for literally everything. Not knowing this might actually reduce the performance. Executing and the creation of these hooks also cost resources.

In this case I would argue to actually not use `useMemo` and re-create the validation scheme every render. It depends a bit on your application but it is recommended to only use these hooks if you have expensive logic and/or components that re-render a lot of times. For a simple validation scheme, it might actually be less performant to memoize than not. Be careful with this.

Comment: Sorry I lost track of this question, but this helped so I marked it as the answer now. You're right on being sensible on using useMemo. In our case they were huge and had a lot of logic inside them. Initially we had them as just objects than anonymous functions, so then it didn't require it.